# jquery Carousel with 2 rows of same images

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

I have a question..Anyone knows a jquery carousel Plugin to do something like this:

http://agencia.canalrp.com/savanahome/images/dummygaleria.jpg

The idea is 2 lines of the same images.. but when i click on the small thumbs, the "slider" on top just center with the selected thumb..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

refer this [bx slider](http://bxslider.com/) plugin you can get that kind of functionality with this